# How to exclude certain users Powershell Password Reset Script

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords

Hey guys need a little help,

I have been rapping my head around how to exclude certain users from a password reset script.

This is the script:

```
$newPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "MyP@ssw0rd" -Force




Import-Csv "C:\users\administrator\desktop\UserCreation.csv" | ForEach-Object {
 $samAccountName = $_."samAccountName"


Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $samAccountName -NewPassword $newPassword -Reset

Set-AdUser -Identity $samAccountName -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false
Write-Host " AD Password has been reset for: "$samAccountName
}
```

I want to exclude certain samAccountNames from this password reset however I cant quite work it out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always set filters in your Set-AdUser comamand.
Like:

```
    Get-ADUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq $true)`
   -and (sAMAccountType -ne 805306370)`
   -and (cn -ne "Administrator")}` 
   -and (SamAccountName -like "*-ext*")`
   -SearchBase "OU=OUwithUsers,DC=MySubdomain,DC=MyDomain,DC=com"
```

You can filter your user list like that or you can modify your csv file by deleting/adding users there. You are using a csv file as an import so that one should have the list of the users that you want to change their passwords.

Personally I would clear the csv or create a csv with more filters so I can then import it and finish what I want to do without worrying if I changed someones password without his permission.

Comment: You Sir are a genius and I am a Idiot for skipping over this. Will just delete the users from the CSV

Answer (score 1):

can you use an exclusion list like this :

```
$exclusion_list = "testuser1","testuser2"

$totalList = ("testuser1","testuser2","testuser4")

    foreach($item in $totalList){
    if( $exclusion_list -contains $item){
    "excluding $item"
    continue
    }
    else{
    #reset the password
    $item
    }

    }
```

Hash table version for performance reasons:

```
$exclusion_list = @{"testuser1"="exclude";"testuser2"="exclude"}

$totalList = ("testuser1","testuser2","testuser4")

foreach($item in $totalList){
if( $exclusion_list[$item]){
"excluding $item"
continue
}
else{
#your code
$item
}

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would work as well but in my case there are too many people to put in a total list we have 500+ users.

Comment: @christian if you are worried about performance , we can use a hashtable. I will add a hashtable version but you might have to create a hashtable from an exclusion list file